# Android API support dictionary applications

Tags: android, dictionary

I am coding a dictionary application. I found a link for Google translate:

[Google translate API support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931245/how-to-use-google-translator-app)

I want my application can give users more definitions of a word (definitions come from Longman, Cambridge, Oxford dictionary, and so on). My question is:

Is there any API support for Android to get those definitions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. And it's called RESTful-API, eg [here](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/oxford-english-dictionary) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/api/v1/documentation/html).

Comment: When making an example I have got stuck because of some unknown reason. Can you please have a look for me Mr Jan. Thank you in adavance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521063/get-stuck-in-a-simple-resful-api-example

Comment: Does this exist for Bibles? I'm searching for Bible API for Android.