# Get the definition of a word programmatically

Tags: android, text, textview

On my iPad, when i touch and hold a specific word in, for example, a PDF document, the word gets highlighted and I get three options, Copy, Search, Define. Choosing the Define option brings up the English definition of the highlighted word in what seems like a built-in dictionary. Is it possible to add this type of functionality to my app using a standard `TextView` without having to create an entire Dictionary database? Does Android already have one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559383/android-api-support-dictionary-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like that built in.  You may be able to find a third party library, but most likely you'd need to build your own from scratch.